# AttributeError . .: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, attributeerror, discord.py

My code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command(self, ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(int(772906069885321236))
    await channel.send(discord.Object(id=772906069885321236), f"{ctx.guild.name} {ctx.author} {ctx.message.clean_content}")
```

I tried using intents but i cant seem to figure them out either

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel), `get_channel` returns `None` if the specified channel could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

`get_channel` returns `None` if the channel could not be found. You can add some error handling to move past this issue *if* that makes sense for the project you're building.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command(self, ctx):
    try:
        channel = client.get_channel(int(772906069885321236))
        await channel.send(discord.Object(id=772906069885321236),
                     f"{ctx.guild.name} {ctx.author} {ctx.message.clean_content}")
    except:
        print("Channel not found")
```